# Call a custom field in an audio shortcode?

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, audio

I'm attempting to call a custom field in an audio shortcode. The field I'm calling, *enclosure*, defines MP3 files that are associated with my respective posts. I'm using the PHP template editor in Wordpress. Here's what I have.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[audio src="enclosure"]');?>
```

I would like to insert the following code in place of the word "enclosure."

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'enclosure', true); ?>
```

I either get the code displayed as text or nothing at all when I paste these snippets together. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [PHP's string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[audio src="'. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'enclosure', true)  .'"]');?>
```

or:

```
<?php
$enclosure = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'enclosure', true);
echo do_shortcode('[audio src="'. $enclosure . '"]';
?>
```